# How to duplicate a div element with a card in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, card

I've found this great tutorial on youtube by CodingNepal (credits to them) where it is basically a a 3d card that flips whenever you hover on, made entirely by CSS and HTML. I want to implement it in a project that I am currently making where it is basically a gallery consisting of 4 rows and multiple column. The problem is I am having a hard time trying to duplicate it in order to achieve the "4 rows and multiple column". How do I do this?

this is the code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Gallery</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallerystyle.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav>
         <div class="logo">
            The Clutch
         </div>
         <input type="checkbox" id="click">
         <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
         <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
         </label>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="Homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Showroom.html">Showroom</a></li>
            <li><a class="active" href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="AboutUs.html">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="center">
         <div class="front-face">
            <div class="contents front">
               <h2>
                 Image is here
                 </h2>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="back-face">
            <div class="contents back">
               <h2>
                Photo Info here
               </h2>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And this is the code for the style sheet. Credits to CodingNepal on youtube for this amazing code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#111212 0%,#ebf9f9 100%);
}
.center,.front-face,
.contents,.back-face{
  position: absolute;
}

.center{
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 400px;
  width: 290px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
 perspective: 1000px;
}

.left{
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 400px;
    width: 290px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
   perspective: 1000px;
  }

  .right{
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 400px;
    width: 290px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
   perspective: 1000px;
  }

.front-face, .back-face{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.2),
              rgba(0,0,0,.2)),url(bg.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transform: translateY(0deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .7s cubic-bezier(.4,.2,.2,1);
}
.contents{
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  perspective: 1000px;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateZ(60px) scale(0.94);
}
.front p{
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: white;
}
.front span{
  font-size: 23px;
  color: white;
}
.front p:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.back-face{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg,#043348 0%,#032535 100%);
}
.back {
  color: white;
}
.back h2{
  font-size: 33px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.back span{
  font-size: 25px;
}
.icons{
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: block;
}
i.fab{
  color:  #042f4b;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.center:hover > .back-face{
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.center:hover > .front-face{
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

The solutions I've tried already is implementing bootstrap but the problem is it destroys the layout of my navbar. I am not that efficient yet in using bootstrap and I am mainly doing the solution via the best of my knowledge about it. I am hoping you can help me with this problem, Thanks!

Comment: put a wrapper div around `<div class="center">` , and give it `position: relative;` before you make multiple cards.

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: I tried wrapping the <div class="center"> and gave it position: relative; but every time I do it it just overlaps the previous one

Comment: you might have to give the wrapper the width and height of .center. Do you have a fiddle or codepen or something? i can take a look at it.

Comment: @dandavis sadly no, I don't have both.

Comment: only the code I provided above